# Trying to prove one set in terms of another using identity laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove: $A\ - (A\cap \ B ) = A - B$

My work thus far

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad A\ - (A\cap \ B) \\
&= (A-A)\ \cap\ (A-B) \text{(using the distributive law)} \\
&= A-B\ \text{(since A-A is just {} (empty set) and the intersection with (A-B) would be A-B)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I think you mean $(A-A)\cup(A-B)$.

Comment: Actually, the intersection of the empty set with any set is the empty set. As Lord the Shark the Unknown states, it's union, not intersection, between $(A-A)$ and $(A-B)$. The union of the empty set with any set is that other set.

Comment: Thé worksheet that I got this from stated the problem as A - (A\cap B)

Comment: With \cap representing intersection

Comment: Set difference does not distribute over intersection in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition of set difference: $X - Y = X \cap Y^c$.

\begin{align*}
&  A - (A \cap B)\\
= & A \cap (A \cap B)^c\\
= & A \cap (A^c \cup B^c)\\
= & (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B^c)\\
= & \emptyset \cup (A \cap B^c)\\
= & A \cap B^c\\
= & A - B
\end{align*}

Comment: To make sure you follow the proof, try filling in the justification for each line.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here is the same proof used by [Austin Mohr](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11245/austin-mohr) but with names of steps added:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
A - (A \cap B) 
&= A \cap (\overline{A \cap B}) & & & & \text{(Definition of set difference)} \\[6pt]
&= A \cap (\bar{A} \cup \bar{B}) & & & & \text{(DeMorgan's law)} \\[6pt]
&= (A \cap \bar{A}) \cup (A \cap \bar{B}) & & & & \text{(Distributive law)} \\[6pt]
&= \varnothing\cup (A \cap \bar{B}) & & & & \text{(Negation law)} \\[6pt]
&= A \cap \bar{B} & & & & \text{(Identity law)} \\[6pt]
&= A - B. & & & & \text{(Definition of set difference)} \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$